# For loop to PING a set of machines using shell script

Tags: shell, for-loop, iteration

I have a set of machines [5 to be precise] and I have to PING them at regular intervals to see if they are alive.

Rather than run 5 separate PING commands on each one of them I am using the for loop of shell script to accomplish the same. But I keep getting this error

```
ping: unknown host 1.2.3.4
```

The for loop that I have used looks like this

```
for every_ip in 1.2.3.4, 2.3.4.5, 3.4.5.6, 4.5.6.7, 5.6.7.8
do
ping $every_ip
done
```

What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not all pings time out when there's no reply, so be sure to specify one - else your loop will stop when one host is down and it will stop you testing the others so they may all appear to be down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No commas in the list of your for loop and better to quote your value:

```
for every_ip in "1.2.3.4" "2.3.4.5" "3.4.5.6" "4.5.6.7" "5.6.7.8"; do
   ping "$every_ip"
done
```